# c++ opencv image not display inside the boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, boost

Im developing `c++` application there i used `boost`, `opencv` . and create the boost thread and call the function inside that thread. the function has got opencv imread ( i checked using cvLoadimage but i got the same result) but programe can't complete and programe exit.

please find below the code i used

```
boost::thread *thread_reconstruct; 

    int main( int argc, const char** argv )
    {

        thread_reconstruct = new boost::thread(  &FuncCreate  );

        return 0;

    }

    void FuncCreate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
          compute_left_descriptors(g_nameRootFolder.c_str());
    }

    }

    void compute_left_descriptors(const char* name_dir)
    {

        char namebuf[1024];


            sprintf(namebuf, "%s/Left/%04d_left.bmp", name_dir, 1);

        // Program ended with exit code: 0 programe exit from here.
        Mat input_left = imread(namebuf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

        imshow("Right View", input_left);
        waitKey(0);

        printf("done\n");
    }
```

Comment: your title says you want to display images but your doesnt use imshow?

Comment: @Micka sorry i'm mistaken . now i put it. still got the same problem.

Comment: @berak i have checked with waitkey(0) in order to apply transform. but results is the same program  exits from Mat input_left = imread(namebuf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); line . any idea ?

Comment: please add cv:: namedWindow ("Right View"); in the main function before thread creation and you have to add a barrier in the main function, something like boost join threads or sth...

Comment: @Micka could you please explain more . thank you.

Comment: 1. you quit your program right after thread creation with return 0. you have to block the quit somehow. 2. sometimes you cant create nee windows in tthreads except the main thread (gui thread) so you should create the output window there.

Comment: Add `thread_reconstruct->join()` before `return` statement in `main` function to synchronize the created thread with the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this version of your code and tell us whether it works or not

```
boost::thread *thread_reconstruct; 

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{

    cv::namedWindow("Right View"); // this will create a window. Sometimes new windows can't be created in another thread, so we do it here in the main function.

    thread_reconstruct = new boost::thread(  &FuncCreate  );

    thread_reconstruct->join(); // this will make your program wait here until the thread has finished processing. Otherwise your program would exit directly.

    return 0;

}

void FuncCreate()
{
    while (true)
    {
      compute_left_descriptors(g_nameRootFolder.c_str());
    }
}

void compute_left_descriptors(const char* name_dir)
{

    char namebuf[1024];


        sprintf(namebuf, "%s/Left/%04d_left.bmp", name_dir, 1);

    // Program ended with exit code: 0 programe exit from here.
    Mat input_left = imread(namebuf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if(input_left.empty()) printf("could not load image\n");

    imshow("Right View", input_left);
    waitKey(0); // if you dont want to press a key before each new image, you can change this to waitKey(30);

    printf("done\n");
}
```