# 'Cannot allocate memory' - OpenCV multiple webcam stream

Tags: c++, opencv, clion

I'm trying to make a live stereovision setup using OpenCV in C++ and two webcams. It is possible to seperately get frames from the two webcams. However, when I try to access them simultaneously in threads, I get a runtime error:

```
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Cannot allocate memory
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/lorre851/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 281
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/lorre851/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:281: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void stream(int camera) {
    VideoCapture cap(camera); // open the default camera
    if(cap.isOpened()) { // check if we succeeded
        while(true) {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
            imshow("Stream " + to_string(camera), frame);
            if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    thread cam1 (stream, 1);
    thread cam2 (stream, 2);


    cam1.join();
    cam2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Anybody got any idea what could be causing this? I'm using CLion on Ubuntu 15.10 LTE.

**UPDATE 1:** I'm using index 1 and 2 for the camera's because I have a built-in camera in my laptop (0) and two USB camera's (1 and 2) plugged in. The USB camera's are the target hardware here.

**UPDATE 2:** Putting both camera feeds in one thread (see code below) works just fine (assuming your USB ports use separate busses, otherwise you'll get a 'NO SPACE LEFT ON DEVICE' error), but the delay between the two frames is noticeable, which is not ideal for a stereovision setup.

```
cv::VideoCapture camera0(0);
cv::VideoCapture camera1(1);

if( !camera0.isOpened() ) return 1;
if( !camera1.isOpened() ) return 1;
cv::Mat3b frame0;
cv::Mat3b frame1;

while(true) {
    camera0 >> frame0;
    camera1 >> frame1;
    if(mat_is_empty(frame0)) cout << "SKIPPED FRAME IN 0";
    else cv::imshow("Stream 0", frame0);

    if(mat_is_empty(frame1)) cout << "SKIPPED FRAME IN 1";
    else cv::imshow("Stream 1", frame1);

    int c = cvWaitKey(40);

    //exit the loop if user press "Esc" key  (ASCII value of "Esc" is 27)
    if(27 == char(c)) break;
}
```

Comment: You say separately, but have you tried a single thread `while(1){ cap1>>frame1;cap2>>frame2; ///...` to access your cameras "jointly"? Your error is not allocation but empty `cv::Mat`. Maybe your USB fails to deliver at that speed (33Hz).

Comment: That seems to be working. However, the delay time between capturing of the frames is noticeable, I don't know if that approach can be used for a stereovision setup. But thanks for the tip, I've been staring at the 'Cannot allocate memory' issue all the time... Might dig in to the OpenCV source or write something else all together to get both camera's working simultaneously.

Comment: `cv::VideoCapture::grab` + retrieve is a worthy substitute but also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286144/c-opencv-image-not-display-inside-the-boost-thread

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I have stupid answer. Your code works fine..

[image]

Count cameras from zero.

```
 thread cam1 (stream, 0);    THIS works
// thread cam2 (stream, 1);  I dont have second camera
```

First of all, I am on windows machine. My cameras are count from 0,1,2 
I do not have second web camera.

In the picture i just use your code and paste cam(0) my web camera 
and for the second camera i use testing rtsp stream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void stream(int camera) {
    VideoCapture cap;
    if (camera == 0) {
        cap.open(0); // open the default camera
    }
    if (camera == 1) {
        cap.open("rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4"); // open the default camera
    }



if (cap.isOpened()) { // check if we succeeded
        while (true) {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
            imshow("Stream " + to_string(camera), frame);
            if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    thread cam1(stream, 0);
    thread cam2(stream, 1);


    cam1.join();
    cam2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, so at least we can be sure the threads are working correctly (it was a pain to get them linked in the cmake file). The problem keeps occuring when I try to open two physical capture devices directly. Sidenote, I have a built-in camera in my laptop + 2 USB Logitech webcams, that's why I'm using 1 and 2 as index (I'll update this in my post).

Comment: If you try only one of them ? Are you able to capture somethink ?