# How to hold window open during OpenCV processing?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, boost

I'm running into an odd problem with OpenCV on Linux, Ubuntu 16.04 specifically.  If I use usual code to show a webcam stream like this it works fine:

```
// WebcamTest.cpp

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // declare a VideoCapture object and associate to webcam, 1 => use 2nd webcam, the 0th webcam is the one integral to the TX2 development board
  cv::VideoCapture capWebcam(1);

  // check if VideoCapture object was associated to webcam successfully, if not, show error message and bail
  if (capWebcam.isOpened() == false)
  {
    std::cout << "error: capWebcam not accessed successfully\n\n";
    return (0);
  }

  cv::Mat imgOriginal;        // input image
  cv::Mat imgGrayscale;       // grayscale of input image
  cv::Mat imgBlurred;         // intermediate blured image
  cv::Mat imgCanny;           // Canny edge image

  char charCheckForEscKey = 0;

  // while the Esc key has not been pressed and the webcam connection is not lost . . .
  while (charCheckForEscKey != 27 && capWebcam.isOpened())
  {
    bool blnFrameReadSuccessfully = capWebcam.read(imgOriginal);            // get next frame

    // if frame was not read successfully, print error message and jump out of while loop
    if (!blnFrameReadSuccessfully || imgOriginal.empty())
    {
      std::cout << "error: frame not read from webcam\n";
      break;
    }

    // convert to grayscale
    cv::cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgGrayscale, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // blur image
    cv::GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, imgBlurred, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);

    // get Canny edges
    cv::Canny(imgBlurred, imgCanny, 75, 150);

    cv::imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal);
    cv::imshow("imgCanny", imgCanny);

    charCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(1);        // delay (in ms) and get key press, if any
  }  // end while

  return (0);
}
```

This example shows the webcam stream in one imshow window and a Canny edges image in a second window.  Both windows update and show the images as expected with very little if any perceptible flicker.

If you're wondering why I'm using the 1th camera instead of the usual 0th camera, I'm running this on a Jetson TX2 and the 0th camera is the one integral to the development board and I'd prefer to use an additional external webcam.  For this same reason I have to use Ubuntu 16.04 but I suspect the result would be the same with Ubuntu 18.04 (have not tested this however).

If instead I have a function that takes significant processing instead of taking simple Canny edges, i.e.:

```
int main(void)
{
  .
  .
  .
  // declare a VideoCapture object and associate to webcam, 1 => use 2nd webcam, the 0th webcam is the one integral to the TX2 development board
  cv::VideoCapture capWebcam(1);

  // check if VideoCapture object was associated to webcam successfully, if not, show error message and bail
  if (capWebcam.isOpened() == false)
  {
    std::cout << "error: capWebcam not accessed successfully\n\n";
    return (0);
  }

  cv::namedWindow("imgOriginal");

  cv::Mat imgOriginal;
  char charCheckForEscKey = 0;

  // while the Esc key has not been pressed and the webcam connection is not lost . . .
  while (charCheckForEscKey != 27 && capWebcam.isOpened())
  {    
    bool blnFrameReadSuccessfully = capWebcam.read(imgOriginal);            // get next frame

    // if frame was not read successfully, print error message and jump out of while loop
    if (!blnFrameReadSuccessfully || imgOriginal.empty())
    {
      std::cout << "error: frame not read from webcam\n";
      break;
    }

    detectLicensePlate(imgOriginal);

    cv::imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal);

    charCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(1);        // delay (in ms) and get key press, if any

  }  // end while
  .
  .
  .
  return (0);
}
```

The `detectLicensePlate()` function takes about a second to run.

The problem I'm having is, when running this program, the window only appears for the slightest amount of time, usually not long enough to even be perceptible, and never long enough to actually see the result.

The strange thing is, the window disappears, then the second or so day occurs for `detectLicensePlate()` to do its thing, then the window appears again for a very short time, then disappears again, and so on.  It's almost as though just after `cv::imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal);`, `cv::destroyAllWindows();` is implicitly being called.

The behavior I'm attempting to achieve is for the window to stay open and continue to show the previous result while processing the next.  From what I recall this was the default behavior on Windows.

I should mention that I'm explicitly declaring the windows with `cv::namedWindow("imgOriginal");` before the while loop in an attempt to not let it go out of scope but this does not seem to help.

Of course I can make the delay longer, i.e.

```
charCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(1500);
```

To wait for 1.5 seconds, but then the application gets very unresponsive.

Based on this post [c++ opencv image not display inside the boost thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286144/c-opencv-image-not-display-inside-the-boost-thread) I tried declaring the window outside the while loop and putting `detectLicensePlate()` and `cv::imshow()` on a separate thread, as follows:

```
  .
  .
  .
  cv::namedWindow("imgOriginal");

  boost::thread myThread;

  // while the Esc key has not been pressed and the webcam connection is not lost . . .
  while (charCheckForEscKey != 27 && capWebcam.isOpened())
  {

    // if frame was not read successfully, print error message and jump out of while loop
    if (!blnFrameReadSuccessfully || imgOriginal.empty())
    {
      std::cout << "error: frame not read from webcam\n";
      break;
    }

    myThread = boost::thread(&preDetectLicensePlate, imgOriginal);
    myThread.join();
    .
    .
    .
  } // end while


// separate function
void preDetectLicensePlate(cv::Mat &imgOriginal)
{
  detectLicensePlate(imgOriginal);
  cv::imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal);
}
```

I even tried putting `detectLicensePlate()` on a separate thread but not `cv::imshow()`, and the other way around, still the same result.  No matter how I change the order or use threading I can't get the window to stay open while the next round of processing is going.

I realize I could use an entirely different windowing environment, such as Qt or something else, and that may or may not solve the problem, but I'd really prefer to avoid that for various reasons.

Does anybody have any other suggestions to get an OpenCV `imshow` window to stay open until the window is next updated or `cv::destroyAllWindows()` is called explicitly?

Comment: What OpenCV version, what HighGUI backend?

Comment: I'm using the Jetson TX2, so I pretty much have to use Ubuntu 16.04 w/JetPack 3.3 which installs OpenCV 3.3.1 on both the host and the device.  I'm not sure what you mean by "HighGUI backend", the above code calls the OpenCV 3.3.1 install.

Comment: By "HighGUI backend" I mean the GUI framework it was configured to use to implement the HighGUI functionality when it was built. On Linux this is likely either GTK or QT..

Comment: I'm using the default Ubuntu 16.04.5 Unity desktop.  I'm under the impression that therefore the windows would generally be rendered via GTK.  If this is not the case then perhaps somebody can correct me on this.